# Magento 2 Programmatically set theme for specific stores

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, admin-controller

Programmatically How can set a theme for specific stores in Magento 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can set theme for specific store using below script.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$config = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Theme\Model\Config"); 
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
```

I have used default luma theme ID, You can change it based on theme.

```
$themeId = 2; 
$theme = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Theme\Model\ThemeFactory")->create()->load($themeId);
```

I have get current storeId, you can set store ID as per your requirement.

```
$storeId= $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
if ($theme->getId()) {
$config->assignToStore($theme,[$storeId],'store');
}
```

If you want to set theme based on website then below is the code.

```
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
if ($theme->getId()) {
$config->assignToStore($theme,[$websiteId],'website');
}
```

Thanks.